# What should you do if suspect your grant submission was plagiarized by a reviewer?

Tags: peer-review

I submitted a grant a few years back to a major UK research council. It was rejected at the time. Since then I was funded to do some/ part  of the work has been funded by another council and I'm thinking about going back to initial council with a new larger grant - hopefully improved with data.

I've have just found a funded grant on that councils page - starting some 3 years after my submission. There is an uncanny overlap with my original grant. It's not copied verbatim but some of the lay summary is uncannily similar. Is it worth me enquiring to the council who reviewed my original grant? Would they care or so anything about it. Would it be detrimental to my career to enquire? I'm a middle career academic

Comment: Your senior colleagues might have some good insights!

Comment: I wonder what the outcome was. Do you have any idea what happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should seriously discuss with someone at your university the possibility of contacting the original funding agency.  Explain carefully the situation to see if this person can confirm that something is indeed strange.  It *could* be a coincidence so another point of view is essential before you go any further.

The funding agency will know who the referees were and if this uncannily similar grant could have come from someone involved with the original refereeing.  Even if you get personally nothing out of it, the grant agency might want to know how such a similar proposal was submitted.

If you decide to go that way, you should not make accusations but merely point that you stumbled upon this project and noticed the significant similarities with your old application.  Let the funding people do their work if they think something’s amiss.